# Can't set a paging contact list in android

Tags: android

My app is taking forever to load,how can I use paging that's it would load me like 10-15 people in a page and not to take 2 minute to my app for loading??
this is my code:
thank's for the help

```
public class Contacts extends Util<Contact> {
    public Contacts(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        list = getContactsBasic();  
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Contact current = list.get(i);

            current.image = getContactImage(current.id);
            if (current.hasPhone) {
                current.phones = getContactPhones(current.id);
            }
        }
    }

    LinkedList<Contact> getContactsBasic() {
        Uri contactsUri = android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null, null);   
        LinkedList<Contact> list = new LinkedList<Contact>();

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do  {
                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int hasPhone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    // add more columns here

                    boolean hasPhoneBoolean; //editor: or simply: boolean hasPhoneBoolean = (hasPhone == 1)

                    if (hasPhone == 1){
                        hasPhoneBoolean = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        hasPhoneBoolean = false;
                    }

                    Contact contact = new Contact(id, name, hasPhoneBoolean);
                    //Contact contact = new Contact(id, name, (hasPhone == 1) ? true : false);

                    list.add(contact);
                } 
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }

    LinkedList<Phone> getContactPhones(int id) {
        Uri phonesUri = android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String filter = android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id);
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(phonesUri, null, filter, null, null);

        LinkedList<Phone> list = new LinkedList<Phone>();
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                    Phone phone = new Phone(number, type);  
                    list.add(phone);
                } 
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null, null);
```

to

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null, "ASC LIMIT " + HOW_MANY_ROWS_YOU_NEED);
```

Comment: sorry but it dosen't really solved my problem,but thanks